# Django. Python. How to get current user's activity log?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I need to pass the current user's entire activity log to an html page, but it seems I cannot find any helpful solution regarding the same.

Is it possible? If yes, please direct me in the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

I found a solution making use of a get() call to django's LogEntry model, but I am clueless as to what shall be the appropriate parameters for doing the same.

Yet another UPDATE:

I am looking for a way to access the activity log of a particular user from the django's log entries WITHOUT saving it to any database

Comment: Check this package 
https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @Zealous : I know about the available plugins, but my question is to find a way without using them

Answer (score 3):

Take a look below listed.....Hope it will help::

```
    lets example::
    Create Two Field  in Models:


    last_activity_ip = models.IPAddressField()
    last_activity_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime(1960, 1, 1))
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
```

Since the User and **UserActivity** models are now related one-to-one we can now type:

Run the Query Like this:

```
a = User.objects.get(username__exact='mpcabd')
print a.useractivity.last_activity_ip

b = UserActivity.objects.get(user=a)
print b.user.username

** To track the activity use this **

    activity = None
    try:
        activity = request.user.useractivity
    except:
        activity = UserActivity()
        activity.user = request.user
        activity.last_activity_date = datetime.now()
        activity.last_activity_ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        activity.save()
        return
    activity.last_activity_date = datetime.now()
    activity.last_activity_ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    activity.save()
```

Comment: Could you tell me what is 'useractivity' in your code?
Also, I need to get the Create/Delete activity of the user, more than the ip and access time.

Comment: useractivity basically the name to OneToOne Field ....That i forgot  to mentioned......  no need to worry...  You can access last_activity_ip directly with instance  that is a....

Comment: last_activity_ip  is the field of UserActivity(MODEL)

Answer (score -1):

This question don't has a short answer, you can use sentry project by side of main django project. below link can helping you:

https://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I am not expecting an answer in code, but just the way to do it. The link provided helps to handle logging which is not what I am planning to do

Comment: Sentry is a powerful logging system you can configure your project for register your project logs to Sentry, in first link you can see some configurations about connecting django project to Sentry...